# Inverse Fourier Transform: $L^2(R) \rightarrow L^2(R)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

We know that the Fourier Transform is a function from $L^2(R)$ to $L^2(R)$.  Is it true for the Inverse Fourier Transform as well? That is, if $f \in L^2(R)$ then does $ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)\in L^2(R)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier Transform function.

Comment: Yes because $f = \check{\hat{\hat{f}}}$ or, as wikipedia says ${\cal F}^{-1} = {\cal F R} = {\cal R F}$.

Comment: Clearly what is true for $f \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2i \pi \xi x}dx$ is true for $f \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2i \pi \xi x}dx$. The Fourier inversion theorem is that the latter is the inverse of the former.

Comment: ok..thanks a lot..Also the relation $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(x)$= $\mathcal{F}(f)(-x)$ holds almost everywhere ??

Comment: How do you define those operators ?..

Comment: The Fourier transform maps $L^2$ onto $L^2$. The operator $\mathcal{F}$ can be defined as $L^2-\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)e^{-2i\pi\xi xdx}dx$.

Comment: Sir, here $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ denotes the Inverse Fourier Transform.